# segfault probably because of pointer problems

Tags: c, pointers

I am kinda new to C and I am trying to write a simple snake remake.
You can view the source on github: https://github.com/blackwolf12333/Snake

When building there are no warnings or errors in the output. But when I run the executable and hit enter it exit's with "Segmentation fault(core dumped)".
I am not a pro yet with pointers, I come from java, and when googling I found that it probably is a problem with pointers.

I have no idea of where it is going wrong because for as far as I know I am doing things right. The problem is when I try to loop through my snake's body_part's.

```
    void print_snake() {
        int i;
        body_part *next = main_snake.head.next;

        move(main_snake.head.pos.x, main_snake.head.pos.y);
        addch('$');
        for(i = 0; i < main_snake.length; i++) { //TODO: segfaults when 'main_snake.length'(should be this) instead of 'main_snake.length - 1'
            printf("1 part");
            print_body_part(next);
            next = next->next;
        }
    }
```

That's from the snake.c file in the repository.

I hope you guys can help me,
greetings blackwolf12333

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to iterate over a chained list, don't use a seperate stop condition. Your `i` variable and `main_snake.length` are not necessary. You can replace

```
for(i = 0; i < main_snake.length; i++)
```

with

```
body_part *next;
for(next = main_snake.head.next; next->next != NULL; next=next->next){
    ...
}
```

Comment: i will try that first thing tomorrow:)

Answer (score 1):

Before going deep through the code it is obvious that when `next` becomes null and `next->next` causes segmentation fault.

In the loop you are starting at a node next to head(`main_snake.head.`**`next`**). Therefore in a list of 4 objects you are processing only 3 objects. In that case iterations should be 3 instead of 4 because `main_snake.length` counts the head also as shown in the function `initialize_snake`. That is why you are getting segmentation fault.

Comment: I realize that, but that shouldn't happen because the length should never be bigger than the amount of next's

Comment: Let me check if that is the problem, would be really stupid:P

Comment: I count the head as part too so the length of 4 should be correct. Also pushed a new commit...

Comment: That should be fixed in the latest source:P but it is still segfaulting:(